# How to get the contents of an InputStream?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I use the following method to get all `.class` files from an `eclipse` project. but the returned files are in `InputStream` format which I can not get the content.

```
public void setFileList(IContainer container) throws CoreException, IOException {
       IResource [] members = container.members();

       for (IResource member : members) {
          if (member instanceof IContainer)  {
              setFileList((IContainer)member);
           } else if (member instanceof IFile && member.isDerived()) {
               IFile file = (IFile)member;

               InputStream contents = file.getContents();
               this.fileList.add(contents);
           }
        }
    }
```

How can I get the contents of this InputStream in a string format or a txt file?

Comment: use apache IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: This returns me java.io.FileInputStream@7fbd1f7d  and not the file

Comment: In this question that was pointed out I could not understand because I do not know what I have to put into encoding

Comment: Class files are binary not text. So what kind of text do you expect for class files?

Comment: I need all the code written in the class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it into a file then you can directly use apache.commons.io helper method:

```
final File outputFile = new File("test.txt");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, outputFile);
```